# How do I keep style information (tags) when undoing and redoing in a Tkinter Text?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.text

I am writing an html editor in Python 3.7.4 / Tkinter 8.6 / Windows 10.0.18362.356, and am using tags to style text for `<em>`, `<strong>` etc. However, the inbuilt undo/redo mechanism deletes these tags, for instance, if I redo immediately after undoing.
Before I go nuts trying to implement my own undo/redo mechanism, is there something I'm missing?

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font

def bold(event=None):
    try:
        textbox.tag_add('bold', 'sel.first', 'sel.last')
    except tkinter.TclError:
        textbox.tag_add('bold', 1.0, 'end')

textbox = tkinter.Text(undo=True)
boldness = tkinter.font.Font(weight='bold')
textbox.tag_config('bold', font=boldness)
textbox.bind('<Control-b>', bold)
textbox.grid()
textbox.mainloop()
```

Now:

1. Run the program.
2. Insert the text `Hello, World!` into the textbox.
3. Select the text `lo, Wo` using the mouse.
4. Press `ctrl-b`. The selected text becomes bold.
5. Press `ctrl-z`. Some or all of the text disappears.
6. Press `ctrl-y`. The text reappears.

Now, I expected from using other word processing programs, that the text would still be tagged when it reappears. However, it is not.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, paste a sample of your code to help.

Comment: ***"However, the inbuilt undo/redo mechanism deletes these tags"***: [Edit] your question and explain in detail this ***"mechanism"***?